# How to recover Intel Edison board

Tags: intel, yocto, u-boot, flash-memory, intel-edison

I had flashed Intel's pre-built src images on board by replacing `u-boot.elf` compiled with buildroot(having support for Edison board).

But the board is stuck on FSBL(FSBL watchdog is continuously rebooting the board). I tried to flash on board, but on board no listener is present to serve flash operation (usually done by `dfu` utility in u-boot). 
So that I am not able to flash pre-built images again.

By this present conditions, how can I bring my board up?
How can I flash images again?

**INPUT** :

Board console o/p

```
******************************
PSH KERNEL VERSION: b0182b2b
            WR: 20104000
******************************

SCU IPC: 0x800000d0  0xfffce92c

PSH miaHOB version: TNG.B0.VVBD.0000000c

microkernel built 11:24:08 Feb  5 2015

******* PSH loader *******
PCM page cache size = 192 KB 
Cache Constraint = 0 Pages
Arming IPC driver ..
Adding page store pool ..
PagestoreAddr(IMR Start Address) = 0x04899000
pageStoreSize(IMR Size)          = 0x00080000

*** Ready to receive application ***
```

In FSBL, is there present any kind of "dfu utility"?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would highly recommend to read this article: https://edison.internet-share.com/wiki/U-Boot

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I have tried this already. The thing is I am not able to see u-boot console to run "run do_force_flash_os" which supports flashing. Board is getting rebooted in FSBL itself(I have already flashed u-boot compiled by buildroot). I think, FSBL is not  able to find appropriate u-boot to boot up and its watchdog is rebooting the board. So my concern is, There should be some jumper that will put board on flashing mode and through j-tag or t-link I can flash the correct images. Please correct me if I am misunderstood.

Comment: Kindly refer board's console under INPUT (editedquestion ) Which is repeatedly being printed.

Comment: In the article above the script is mentioned that prepares and flashes image via DnX protocol. You have to install *xFSTK* flasher. One more thing, I'm not sure you did everything according to instructions. There's **no** mention of *u-boot.elf*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I mean, after messing up with u-boot loader. Now on ubuntu 16.04, I am not able to install xfstk. I am getting following error."g++: error: /usr/lib/libusb.a: No such file or directory". I am trying to resolve this. I will you posted. and I posted same question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48333002/install-xfstk-in-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

For installation fstk, I had asked question for the same.

Kindly refer Question mentioned below.

[Install XFSTK in ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48333002/install-xfstk-in-ubuntu-16-04/48360993#48360993)

Along with this, prebuilt bins are received for recover edison board