# Install XFSTK in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, flash-builder, libusb, lib, intel-edison

I am trying to install XFSTK in Ubuntu 16.04(64 bit). I followed [XFSTK](https://communities.intel.com/thread/56121) to install this package.

While building package, it throws [This Error](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Tizy5Dcf0LnMJFwlyCBBojs16bHcGUcn).

INPUT : 
      libusb is already installed in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb.a.

I created symlink in /usr/lib/, It threw Linking error (ld).

So how can i install xfstk on 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04 ?

Comment: Take binaries from here: https://github.com/htot/meta-intel-edison/wiki/6.4-Recovery

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response.

Answer (score 0):

The prebuilt images for xfstk worked, And for **libboost_program_options.so.1.62.0** lib, I had to install **libboost-all-dev** package. And finally u-boot console came up.