# How to flash images built for intel edison using buildroot

Tags: u-boot, buildroot, intel-edison

I have built images for intel Edison board using **edison supported buildroot** on ubuntu 17.10 (64 bit).

I followed following steps

1 . **make edison_defconfig.**

2 . **make**

and Images are installed in output/images.

But when I tried to flash u-boot on board using [**This Link**](https://edison.internet-share.com/wiki/U-Boot),

3 . Then I did  **truncate -s %4096 u-boot.bin** in output/images

4 . **dfu-util -v -d 8087:0a99 --alt u-boot0 -D u-boot.bin**

5 . **run do_force_flash_os** on board

I am able to flash the u-boot on board successfully. 
But board is not booting up with new u-boot .

What is process to use images built from buildroot ?

How to flash **bzImage** and **.img** file on board from output/images ?

Comment: It's not clear what the errors you get. Second question (about *bzImage*) is non-sense until you will have working U-Boot. (Besides, the steps 4 and 5 in your list are in reversed order, first you need to issue a command in the command line, after you run `dfu` from host)

Comment: Btw, have you read a section *Known bugs* there?

Comment: Yes, I am able to boot the board with the u-boot given in link (git). Then i can recover board as "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48160395/how-to-recover-intel-edison-board?noredirect=1#comment83620490_48160395", And now i would like too use images built by buildroot. These  images are flashed but u-boot is not getting booted up.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why do you need a recover procedure?

Comment: Since, with u-boot image built by buildroot, board is not able run this u-boot. Board is always being ready to receive application. So that to work board as earlier or flash it again, I need to recover the board